# How to get a uniform temperature across all rooms with underfloor heating?

Tags: heating, temperature

We bought an apartment with underfloor heating (w/ CH boiler) and I've been having difficulties getting a uniform temperature across all rooms.

The problem is that the thermostat is set up in the main living room where we have large windows. The sun heats up the room quite nicely so that the thermostat reaches the target temperature in that room, after which the underfloor heating pump shuts down.

This of course means that the other rooms, where it is sometimes much colder, are not heated properly. What can I do to prevent this from happening?

I know that I could invest in zoning-technology. However, it is quite expensive and I want to avoid this.

Comment: If you don't want to go to zones, move the thermostat to a different room that doesn't get so much solar gain, as well as the balancing that @DDS suggests.

Answer (score 2):

You have to balance all the circuits: start reducing flow to the ones going to hotter rooms (it will cool a little hotter room and also distribute more hot water to the others colder ones).

Go to the main collector and reduce by 1/10 the flow to hot room (say if it's 10L/min reduce it to 9 L/m) There should be a transparent meter, on every circuit, telling the current flow (obviously the reading is valid if made with the heating system on and the thermostat calling)

This set up is quite time consuming (you see effects at least with a 1-day delay but once you reach your optimum it's done)

Comment: Wow. That last sentence is _important_! You can't make an adjustment and expect a change right away. This will take patience...

Comment: The rooms may be in series, if so would throttle a group of the units. I would like to see some pictures mainly by the pump and how it is distributed. Also if there is more than one circuit reducing one will increase the flow in the other circuits. The pump has a "head" capacity and will not move more water once this is reached so when you throttle do it in small increments.